# When to use ambient while searching for a type definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsd

I'm currently migrating from tsd to typings since it's deprecated.
but It's not crystal clear when I need to use `--ambient` or not when looking for a definition.

Also: is it correct to say that the goal of typings, in the longterm, is to completely move away from ambiant declatation from DefintelyTyped and only rely on the typings registry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but It's not crystal clear when I need to use --ambient

## Always Ambient Stuff

Stuff that changes the nature of the *global* environment (e.g. `node.d.ts`) will always be *ambient*.

## Modules

For stuff that is a module (e.g. a node package like `debug`) it can be converted into a *typings module* (and in fact has been) so you don't need `--ambient`.

However you can still use the definition from DefinitelyTyped if you use `--ambient`. Also if the conversion hasn't taken place to *typings* you can *only* use `--ambient`.

Comment: oups sorry, I'm not very famililar with SO.