# how do i install a listed typings?

Tags: typescript, tsd

I'm using a library with Typescript, and getting a compiler error.

> public/components/chatlogs.ts(25,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Handsontable'.

it seems there is a typings for it:

```
$ typings search handsontable
Viewing 2 of 2

NAME                SOURCE HOMEPAGE                  DESCRIPTION UPDATED                 
handsontable        dt     https://handsontable.com/             2016-04-12T15:30:16.000Z
jquery-handsontable dt     http://handsontable.com               2016-03-29T17:54:46.000Z
```

but then i cant install that?

```
$ typings install handsontable
typings ERR! message Unable to find "handsontable" for "npm" in the registry. Did you want to install ambient typings with the ambient flag? If you can contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/handsontable/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

typings ERR! cwd /Users/dc/dev/rikai/boteditor
typings ERR! system Darwin 15.3.0
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/iojs" "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install" "handsontable"
typings ERR! node -v v5.1.1
typings ERR! typings -v 0.7.12

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
➜  boteditor git:(master) ✗
```

Is there some way to use a different "source" than npm?

```
typings help install

Usage: typings <command>

Commands:
    bundle, i, in, info, init, install, la, list, ll, ls, open, r, remove, rm,
    search, uninstall, view

typings <command> -h   Get help for <command>
typings <command> -V   Enable verbose logging

typings --version      Print the CLI version

typings@0.7.12 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typings
```

How do I install a typings that is listed with a different homepage?

Or maybe they exist for tsd but not typings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe `global` has replaced `ambient` as a keyword, 
and `source~packagename` is the syntax, for example:

```
typings install dt~node --global
```

still unclear what the `env` or `dt` typings repo distinctions are. surely `dt` is the default place that is searched, so why is there a need to specify it?

Answer (score 1):

> but then i cant install that

Type definitions in DefinitelyTyped are considered `ambient`. So you need to install with the ambient flag:

```
typings install --ambient handsontable
```

## More on ambient

[When to use ambient while searching for a type definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397954/when-to-use-ambient-while-searching-for-a-type-definition/36414912#36414912)

Comment: this is out of date now, the incantation has changed to `global`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly copy a typings file from [Definitely Typed Typescript](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and paste it in your project.

You can also download the whole definitely typed github project from above link, copy and paste the required typings files according to your need.

As @basarat told

```
typings install --ambient fileName
```

would be an another option to download typings file.

For more info on typings file, like how to use them, what they contain look at [Definitely Typed](http://definitelytyped.org/).

Regards

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

The ERR message actually suggest what you should do (adding line breaks for SO):

```
$ typings install handsontable
typings ERR! message Unable to find "handsontable" for "npm" in the registry.
Did you want to install ambient typings with the ambient flag?
If you can contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
```

To get the help message on typings, you should do

```
typings <command> -h
```

In this case

```
typings install -h

typings install (with no arguments, in package directory)
typings install [<name>=]<location>

  <name>      Module name of the installed definition
  <location>  The location to read from (described below)

Valid Locations:
  [<source>!]<pkg>[@<version>][#<tag>]
  file:<path>
  github:<org>/<repo>[/<path>][#<commitish>]
  bitbucket:<org>/<repo>[/<path>][#<commitish>]
  npm:<pkg>[/<path>]
  bower:<pkg>[/<path>]
  http(s)://<host>/<path>

  <source>    The registry mirror (E.g. "npm", "bower", "env", "global", "dt", ...)
  <path>      Path to a `.d.ts` file or `typings.json`
  <host>      A domain name (with optional port)
  <version>   A semver range (E.g. ">=4.0")
  <tag>       The specific tag of a registry entry
  <commitish> A git commit, tag or branch

Options:
  [--save|-S]       Persist to "dependencies"
  [--save-dev|-D]   Persist to "devDependencies"
  [--save-peer|-P]  Persist to "peerDependencies"
  [--ambient|-A]    Install and persist as an ambient definition
    [-SA]           Persist to "ambientDependencies"
    [-DA]           Persist to "ambientDevDependencies"
  [--production]    Install only production dependencies (omits dev dependencies)

Aliases: i, in
```

> Is there some way to use a different "source" than npm?

You can configure the `defaultSource` and `defaultAmbientSource` in `.typingsrc`.

Answer (score 0):

try using the following command
if there is a source for dt or env

typings install --global en~node

Comment: whats the difference between en~node and dt~node - since dt is where the typing is listed as existing?