# typings always complaining about global module

Tags: module, typescript, global, external

I am very new to typescript. Whatever typings I try to install, I get:

> typings ERR! message Attempted to compile "angular" as an external module, but it looks like a global module.

I am just trying to do

```
typings install dt~angular
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
If you are coming here with little knowledge (as I was when writing this question) - consider using npm/@types. [More info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/) and [discussion](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/600).

Comment: i used to install typings using following command:- typings install angular --ambient --save.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As error message suggests, you should use --global option:

```
typings install dt~angular --global --save
```

See detailed step-by-step tutorial for setting up Node.js project with TypeScript support in [IntelliJ IDEA / Webstorm](https://memz.co/typescript-nodejs-intellij-idea-webstorm/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://memz.co/typescript-nodejs-visual-studio-code/)

TypeScript and tools around it are evolving very fast. What worked yesterday don't work any more.

Comment: Is there a place with up-to-date description of global modules? At first I thought it is similar npm global, which is not really what I wanted...

Answer (score -4):

> What am I doing wrong?

Global modules need to be compiled with `--ambient`

```
typings install angular --ambient --save
```

You can see more on *the need to use `ambient`* here : [When to use ambient while searching for a type definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397954/when-to-use-ambient-while-searching-for-a-type-definition/36414912#36414912)

Comment: The "ambient" option was renamed to "global" in typings 1.x