# I want to enable intellisense for angular 1.6 in VS code . Getting error while installing angular with typings

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, npm-install, angularjs-1.6

I am getting the following error.

```
typings install dt~angular --global typings ERR! message Attempted to    compile "angular" as a global module, but it l ooks like an external    module. You'll need to remove the global option to continu e. typings    ERR! typings ERR! cwd C:\Users\Debjit typings ERR! system Windows_NT
   6.2.9200 typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Debjit\\A    ppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install"    "dt~angular " "--global" typings ERR! node -v v6.9.1 typings ERR!    typings -v 2.1.0 typings ERR! typings ERR! If you need help, you may    report this error at: typings ERR!    <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

While the follwing modules are there

```
npm list -g --depth=0

+-- bower@1.7.9

+-- cordova@6.1.1

+-- gulp@3.9.1

+-- ionic@1.7.14

+-- typescript@2.1.4    

`-- typings@2.1.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typings always complaining about global module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357619/typings-always-complaining-about-global-module)

Comment: the solution in the ealier answer does not work. I also posted in github it says "It is no longer a global definition. " I am bit confused.

Comment: In any case I recommend switching to `@types`